# Setting project properites in gradle task for a project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

Adding the following line to gradle.properties 
`project.setProperty("android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class","testing")`

will throw an error that 
`Could not set unknown property 'android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

But running the command `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=testing`

will add this to project properties that i can verify from project.getProperties() method.Can some why explain how to resolve the error.

Comment: Please mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i have to delcare the property name in the gradle.properties file under project directory to resolve the issue